# Firebase Firestore Database Rules: using arrays from another document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to make a web app that displays different elements based on what permissions I give to a user.

All the permissions are stored in the the Cloud Firestore database at /users/{userId} in the field "permissions", which is an array containing the permissionId's.

In /photo_libraries/{libraryId} I have a field called permissionId, which is a string.

I now want to give users that have the right permissionId to be able to read the document in /photo_libraries/{libraryId} that has that permissionId.

I've tried this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /photo_libraries/{libraryId} {
        allow read: if get(/database/$(database)/documents/photo_libraries/$(libraryId)).data.permissionId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permissions;
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I'm quite new to the Firestore rules. Can anyone help me out?

P.S. This is how my database looks like:
[image: users]

[image: photo_libraries]

This is the code I try to run:

```
const db = firebase.firestore(); const auth = firebase.auth();
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        db.collection('photo_libraries').get().then(snapshot => {
            // set up the UI
        }, err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    } else {
        // Logging out stuff
    };
});
```

In the console I get the error message:

`Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Thank you,

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /photo_libraries/{libraryId} {
        allow read: if resource.data.permissionId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permissions;
    }
  }
}
```

But a better solution would be to add the `persmissions` array as a custom claim, then you dont need to call `get`.

When querying Firestore make sure you are only querying the documents you can actually access. Look for "rules are not filter" on google and you will get plenty of hits on SO and in the official Firebase documentation.

Comment: When I run `const db = firebase.firestore(); const auth = firebase.auth();
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        db.collection('photo_libraries').get().then(snapshot => {
            // set up the UI
        }, err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    } else {
        // Logging out stuff
    };
});` It gives me an error message in the console saying "Missing or insufficient permissions.", even with your suggested answer. P.S. I've added some pictures to the post of the database.

Comment: You need to make sure you are only querying the documents you can actually access. Look for "rules are not filter" on google and you will get plenty of hits on SO and in the official Firebase documentation

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip! I figured it out, I used: `db.collection('photo-libraries').where("permissionId", "in", userPermissions)`